# using eof on C++

Tags: c++, input, pascal, eof

i am looking for C++ coding for this pascal code

```
var
jumlah,bil : integer;
begin
jumlah := 0;
while not eof(input) do
begin
   readln(bil);
   jumlah := jumlah + bil;
end;
writeln(jumlah);
end.
```

i don't understand using eof on C++

it's purpose is to calculate data from line 1 to the end of the file

edit : 
well i tried this but no luck

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int k,sum;
    char l;
    cin >> k;
    while (k != NULL)
    {
          cin >> k;
          sum = sum + k;
    }
    cout << sum<<endl;
}
```

sorry i am new to C++

Comment: Which IO functions are you using?

Comment: You need to understand the purpose of the code, then recode that purpose in C++, not try to get a 1-1 translation. There are many answers on how to read the lines from a file. (hit: `std::getline`)

Comment: @David: It's not that we can't, but we won't answer "please give meh tha codez" questions.

Comment: i give u what i have tried so far but still no luck. no idea how to convert `while not eof(input) do` to C++

Comment: @Code Monkey I would happily answer it. Like this: #include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  int jumlah = 0;
  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    jumlah += atoi(line.c_str());
  std::cout << jumlah << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

Comment: With a bit of editing this could be a useful question on how to work with EOF issues in C++.

Comment: @Brian: And then it would be a duplicate.

Comment: @David thanks, can you explain what this is mean `c_str()`

Comment: @Robert: Take your pick - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=EOF

Comment: @Code Monkey - Are you sure it is a "give me the codes questions?" He has shown what he has tried so far. He is new here. You are giving this guy a hard time because his native language is not English. Give him the benefit of the doubt. The stackoverflow users can help edit his question. This is why stackoverflow isn't fun anymore.

Comment: @Brian: I don't know what his language is; but anyways - look at the close reason "too localized". And it was one of those "please give meh tha codez" questions. Before it was edited, it just said - "I have this in Pascal, please convert to C++". Even Dider said, "What have you tried so far?"

Comment: @zeulb `string::c_str()` generates a null-terminated sequence of characters (c-string) with the same content as the string object and returns it as a pointer to an array of characters.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Comment: @Code Monkey - I don't agree with that close reason. If you let stackoverflow take its course, the question can be edited and made useful to many more people. Instead you are turning off a potential new user to the site.

Comment: @Brian: If you say so, I'm not a moderator so I can't lock it. I can only vote - along with 4 other people. The system is working as designed (it has 3 reopen votes so far).

Comment: @Code Monkey - again, he is new here. He did post what he tried after he was asked.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, after it was closed.

Comment: Question reopened which is nice; you have two answers which are much better than my Pascal-ish version, written by real C++ programmers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're pretty close, but probably being influenced a bit more by your Pascal background than is ideal. What you probably want is more like:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;   // Bad idea, but I'll leave it for now.

int main()
{
    int k,sum = 0; // sum needs to be initialized.
    while (cin >> k)
    {
          sum += k;  // `sum = sum + k;`, is legal but quite foreign to C or C++.
    }
    cout << sum<<endl;
}
```

Alternatively, C++ can treat a file roughly like a sequential container, and work with it about like it would any other container:

```
int main() { 
    int sum = std::accumulate(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 
                              std::istream_iterator<int>(),
                              0);    // starting value
    std::cout << sum << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The usual idiom is

```
while (std :: cin >> var) {
   // ...
}
```

The `cin` object casts to false after `operator>>` fails, usually because of EOF: [check badbit, eofbit and failbit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/).

Answer (score 4):

To format what David wrote above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int jumlah = 0;
    std::string line;
    while ( std::getline(std::cin, line) )
        jumlah += atoi(line.c_str());

    std::cout << jumlah << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can also find more information at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/

Comment: I think I would use the regular `std::cin >> int` instead of getline, but this more closely models his pascal code.

Comment: +1 (how you could I not upvote?!!) but I like the other idiomatic C++ versions better.